# Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed

Tags: luatex

Now I face another problem in latex. how to solve this problem.

```
Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: 
C:\Users\Maa-Baba-Asad\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log. Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you confirm this error message comes for all files or some particular file? If this for some particular file, then please post your code as `MWE`...

Comment: When I use twentyseconds cv template then this problem arises.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `luatex` when you seem to be using `pdflatex`?

Comment: You should have more error logs above this. For example, I have seen this error when the output pdf file was not writable. Would you please put up a minimal compilable example?